# Is there any way to get an object from a json object that has an unpredictable key/name?

Tags: javascript, json

JSON object:

```
{
  "users": {
    "1403365934870556481": {
      "userId": "1403365934863466416",
      "id": "1403365934870556481",
      "relationType": "CHILD",
      "nickname": "Nameson",
      "active": "1",
      "created": "2014-06-21 16:52:14",
      "relationDetails": {
        "userId": "1403365934863466416",
        "title": "UNSELECTED",
      },
      "hasFinanceAccount": true
    },
    "1406296959993232380": {
      "userId": "1406296959978437904",
      "id": "1406296959993232380",
      "relationType": "CHILD",
      "nickname": "Izzy",
      "active": "1",
      "created": "2014-07-25 15:02:39",
      "relationDetails": {
        "userId": "1406296959978437904",
        "title": "UNSELECTED",
       },
      "hasFinanceAccount": true
    }
  }
}
```

Scheme of the object:

```
          --> somenumber -> obj
obj->users
          --> somenumber -> obj
```

The only thing I can think is parse that object as string and replace the number with something else

any suggestion?

My Solution is:

```
var tmp = JSON.stringify( currentPageData.getChildren );
    tmp = t.replace(/[\d]+\"\:\{\"userId/g, 'child":{"userId');
    myobj = JSON.parse(tmp);
```

Comment: JSON keys must be strings - what you have is a Javascript Object.

Comment: Actually I don't know the number

Comment: @Donovant Can you post more details about what you are trying to do then? I don't understand.

Comment: The fact that the name is a number is irrelevant. You would have the same problem if the name is a bunch of random letters. The problem is that the name is not predictable. You can enumerate keys to find them.

Comment: fyi: you _serialize_ an object into a string, and strings can be _parsed_ into objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myobj = {
    3: "three"
}

console.log(myobj[3]) // prints "three"
```

Comment: I don't know the number... so actually I'm asking how I can get the object array-like

Comment: @Donovant Can you be a bit clearer? does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys help?

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = { 1234567890: 'test', asdf: 'okay' };
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(obj[keys[0]]); // 'test'
console.log(obj[keys[1]]); // 'okay'
```

## update

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var values = Object.keys(obj.users).map(function(key){ return obj.users[key]});
values.forEach(function(value){
    if (value["userId"]){
        console.log(value["nickname"]);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5E67q/1/)

Comment: Object.keys(obj).map(function(a){return this[a]}, obj) will give you an array of values

Comment: @dandavis, yup but it requires [jquery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) right ? we can just loop using for 0 .. keys.length

Comment: [].map() came along well before jQuery (thanks to Prototype.js), and has been native for years.